# CFWheels - Plugins get deleted for no apparent reason

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I had issues with plugins earlier, but it turned out to be a glitch with my host 'Hostek'. Okay I thought, I'll setup a local Railo / Tomcat environment and work locally.

All works well...except plugins...again!

No matter what I seem to do, CFWheels will delete / remove any plugin folder dropped into the plugin directory. It's driving me absolutely mad.

I have even toggled around with the settings:

```
<cfset set(overwritePlugins = false) />
<cfset set(cachePlugins = true) />
```

And it seems to make no difference, even after 'reloading' the app. I've tried lots of different things and now I'm out of ideas.

I'm using the latest Railo, the latest CFWheels and I'm on a Mac with Lion.

As I said, everything else seems to work as expected, but anything I put in this particular folder, then gets deleted when I do something as simple as refresh a page on my app.

What the?? I like CFWheels, but I'm on the verge of trying something else because this seems to have gone on for far too long.

Please help a desperate newcomer.

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Are the zip files for the plugin in the plugins folder?  If not, that's the problem. If you remove the zip file then cfwheels will remove the plugin. Also, worth using plugin manager if not already. Stick with cfwheels. It will pay off!!

Comment: Hi Jason, that is EXACTLY it! Thank you so much. I was unzipping and placing the folder itself in there. Doh! Write this in an answer and I'll mark you as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the zip files for the plugin in the plugins folder? If not, that's the problem. If you remove the zip file then cfwheels will remove the plugin. Also, worth using plugin manager if not already. Stick with cfwheels.

If you don't use Plugin Manager, all you need to do is drop the plugins zip folder into the plugins folder.  To remove a plugin, you just delete the zip file.

All that being said, highly recommend using the plugin manager.

Have fun with cfwheels.. you will love it!

Comment: Thanks. That did it. As mentioned before...I did not know that plugins had to remain within their ZIP folder. I extracted and uploaded it, which was wrong; for anyone who might come across this same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the "Plugin Settings" section of the [Configuration and Defaults](http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/chapter/configuration-and-defaults) chapter.

The `deletePluginDirectories` setting reads like this:

> When set to true, Wheels will remove subdirectories within the `plugins` folder that do not contain corresponding plugin zip files. Set to `false` to add convenience to the process for developing your own plugins.

In my opinion, the best practice is to set this to `false` in `design` mode but leave it at `true` in the others. But you need to make sure you have it packaged in a zip file before moving to a different environment, or else it'll delete all of your code just like you described.